# Upgrade TP-Link TL-WR841ND v7 to DD-WRT v24-sp2 (22/12/14) is not working

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

Before this, my TP-Link router was working fine, but I wanted to try DD-WRT because I heard of wireless stability and more features. So I upgraded my TP-Link TL-WR841ND v7 to `dd-wrt-tp-link-tl-wr841n`.

After doing that, the wireless connection to the router is not successful. I cannot connect; it just keeps on loading with no errors.

I have to manually assign an IP address for my PC to access the upgraded router even after IP release and renew.
Can you please help?

I used this link as a guide:
http://greggborodaty.com/installing-dd-wrt-tp-link-tl-wr841n/.

Comment: What level of functionality do you have after manually assigning an IP address?  Can you access the Internet, or just talk to the router?

Comment: Did you use an image from the router database?

Comment: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firmware_FAQ#Where_do_I_download_firmware.3F

Answer (score 0):

You can access the internet after setting a static IP, can't you? If so, it means the DHCP function doesn't work. Try logging in to the router, uncheck DNSMasq in the services tab, then uncheck DNSMasq at the DHCP Server part in Setup/Basic Setup tab (please remember to click save button after each change then apply settings after all). After that, you can reboot the router. Hope it works. BTW, I am using build 25544, it is stable for me.

Cheers